# Present Perfect VS Past Perfect depending on context

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Is this sentence correct:

> I remember a lot of interesting stories happened here.

Unless I want to write the full sentence it will be pretty fine.

But:

> I remember a lot of interesting stories that has happened here.

And in this context I should change the Present Perfect part with Past Perfect.

> Last summer I visited the places where I had spent my childhood. I remember a
>   lot of interesting stories that had happened here.

Or I'd rather write:

> Last summer I visited the places where I had spent my childhood. I
>   remembered a
>   lot of interesting stories that had happened here.

Comment: **went to** sounds too simple. **Last summer I visited the places where I spent my childhood. I remember a lot of interesting stories that happened there.**

Comment: Both **remember** and **remembered** are possible.

Comment: @SovereignSun, I've rewritten it. It was a mechanical typo. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say it was a mistake.

Comment: @SovereignSun, so, if we don't pay attention to the reduced adjective clause, we will say had happened?

Comment: @SovereignSun, I'm terribly sorry, for bothering you, but can a rely on your help: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143595/having-deal-with-verbs-choices

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the perfect at all. You can keep it to simple aspect, past tense:

> Last summer I visited the places where I had spent my childhood. I remembered a lot of interesting stories **that happened** here.

Actually, you can lose the *had* in the first sentence, too.

Now, I can question your use of *here*, where I might use *there*. I can question the idea of *stories* that *happened*. But there's really no need to complicate the question of tense and aspect here. Things happened, in the past. Simple past is all that is necessary.